# Object Browser / Class Browser for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am just getting started with Visual Studio Code.  I am really liking it better than the full Visual Studio, but I was wondering how to show the object browser?

Along the left icon bar where I would expect it to be, all I see is Explorer, Search, Source Control, Run, and Extensions.  Then at the bottom are Accounts and Settings.

How do I show the object browser?  Is there a setting somewhere, or do I need to install an extension, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I could not find it using the explanation above, I found the Object Browser under the View menu, somewhere at the middle of the list.
Or...you can press CTRL+ALT+J

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7tP2.png)

Comment: the question here is about VS Code and not Visual Studio.

Comment: This is not the correct answer

Answer (score 9):

I found it.

Just in case anyone is as blind as I am and stumbles across this question:

Under the "Explorer" button on the left.  Way down at the bottom there is an "OUTLINE" section.  Twirl that open and there it is!